# ZeroMQ is blocked in context.close(). How to safely close socket and context in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

### Description

A broadcaster broadcasts messages in a PUB socket "tcp://localhost:5556" and a STOP control signal in another PUB socket "tcp://localhost:5557".
A listener receives messages. It stops and quits as soon as it hears the STOP control signal.

As documented in 0MQ Termination white paper, to stop a recv() waiting, it is a standard method to terminate the underlying context and the recv() will quit with throwing an ETERM excpetion.

Although recv() block is released, the context.close() is blocked instead. As a result, the program still cannot be safely quit.

In addition, **close the socket** before context and **set the linger value to 0** of subscriber socket has been implemented. Still, it is blocked.

- [system  ]: Ubuntu 18.04.1(Linux 4.18.0-17-generic)
- [compiler]: gcc-g++ version 7.3.0
- [ZeroMQ  ]: libzmq 4.3.1 + cppzmq 4.3.0

### Reproducing Code

Here is a simple but complete code to reproduce the problem.

```cpp
// Class Broadcast: A Broadcast object sends a message every 10ms,
//                  and finally sends a stop control signal
//     - start()  : start broadcasting.
class Broadcast {
public:
    Broadcast():
        context_(1),
        publisher_(context_, ZMQ_PUB),
        controller_(context_, ZMQ_PUB)
    {
        publisher_.bind("tcp://*:5556");
        controller_.bind("tcp://*:5557");
    }

    void start(){
        std::cout << "start Broadcast" << std::endl;
        // send data through publisher
        const int send_time = 5;
        const std::string foo_template("foo_");
        for(int i = 0; i < send_time; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            std::string foo = foo_template + std::to_string(i);
            zmq::message_t msg(foo.size());
            std::memcpy(msg.data(), foo.c_str(), foo.size());
            std::cout << "Broadcast: " << foo << std::endl;
            publisher_.send(msg);
        }
        // send stop control signal throgh controller
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        std::string stop("bar");
        zmq::message_t msg(stop.size());
        std::memcpy(msg.data(), stop.c_str(), stop.size());
        std::cout << "Broadcast Control Signal: " << stop << std::endl;
        controller_.send(msg);
        std::cout << "end Broadcast" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    zmq::context_t context_;
    zmq::socket_t  publisher_;
    zmq::socket_t  controller_;
}; // class Broadcast
```

```cpp
// Class Listener : A Listener object receives messages from Broadcast
//                  until it receives a stop control signal.
//     - start()  : start receiving messages;
//     - control(): start receiving control signals;
//     - stop()   : set stop_flag and close zmq sockets and context

class Listener {
public:
    Listener():
        stop_(false),
        context_(1),
        subscriber_(context_, ZMQ_SUB),
        controller_(context_, ZMQ_SUB)
    {
        subscriber_.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
        controller_.connect("tcp://localhost:5557");
        int linger = 0;
        subscriber_.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, nullptr, 0);
        subscriber_.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));
        controller_.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, nullptr, 0);
        controller_.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));
    }

    void start() {
        std::cout << "start Listener" << std::endl;
        stop_ = false;
        auto control_future = std::async([this]{ control(); });
        while(!stop_) {
            try {
                zmq::message_t msg;
                subscriber_.recv(&msg);
                std::string msg_str{static_cast<char*>(msg.data()), msg.size()};
                std::cout << "Received : " << msg_str << std::endl;
            } catch(const zmq::error_t& ex) {
                // recv() throws ETERM when the zmq context is destroyed,
                // as when AsyncZmqListener::Stop() is called
                if(ex.num() != ETERM)
                    throw;
                std::cerr << "subscriber stop with ETERM" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "wait control to join..." << std::endl;
        control_future.get();
        std::cout << "end Listener" << std::endl;

    }

    void control() {
        while(!stop_) {
            zmq::message_t ctrl;
            controller_.recv(&ctrl);
            std::string ctrl_str{static_cast<char*>(ctrl.data()), ctrl.size()};
            std::cout << "Received  Control Signal: " << ctrl_str << std::endl;
            if(ctrl_str == "bar") {
                stop();
            }
        }
    }

    void stop() {
        stop_ = true;
        std::cerr << "closing context..." << std::endl;
        subscriber_.close();
        controller_.close();
        context_.close();
        std::cerr << "context is closed." << std::endl;
    }

private:
    volatile bool  stop_;
    zmq::context_t context_;
    zmq::socket_t  subscriber_;
    zmq::socket_t  controller_;
}; // class Listener
```

```cpp
// ## Problem
// Client cannot safely quit since context_.close() blocks the thread.

#include "zmq.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Broadcast broadcast;
    Listener  listener;

    auto broadcast_future = std::async([&]{ broadcast.start(); });
    auto listener_future  = std::async([&]{ listener.start() ; });

    broadcast_future.get();
    listener_future.get();

    std::cout << "ALL COMPLETED" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Result

This problem appears **with possibility**, you may have to run several times to reproduce it once. There are three possible results: the correctly exit version, the abort version and the blocked version.

#### Correct version

if program exit correctly it will display:

```
➜  zmq_safe_quit ./a.out
start Listener
start Broadcast
Broadcast: foo_0
Received : foo_0
Broadcast: foo_1
Received : foo_1
Broadcast: foo_2
Received : foo_2
Broadcast: foo_3
Received : foo_3
Broadcast: foo_4
Received : foo_4
Broadcast Control Signal: bar
end Broadcast
Received  Control Signal: bar
closing context...
subscriber stop with ETERM
wait control to join...
context is closed.
end Listener
ALL COMPLETED
```

#### Blocked version

```
➜  zmq_safe_quit ./a.out
start Listener
start Broadcast
Broadcast: foo_0
Received : foo_0
Broadcast: foo_1
Received : foo_1
Broadcast: foo_2
Received : foo_2
Broadcast: foo_3
Received : foo_3
Broadcast: foo_4
Received : foo_4
Broadcast Control Signal: bar
end Broadcast
Received  Control Signal: bar
closing context...
context is closed.
```

The "end Listener" is missing and shell is blocked.

#### Abort version

```
start Listener
start Broadcast
Broadcast: foo_0
Received : foo_0
Broadcast: foo_1
Received : foo_1
Broadcast: foo_2
Received : foo_2
Broadcast: foo_3
Received : foo_3
Broadcast: foo_4
Received : foo_4
Broadcast Control Signal: bar
end Broadcast
Received  Control Signal: bar
closing context...
Assertion failed: pfd.revents & POLLIN (/home/davidwu/src/libzmq/src/signaler.cpp:264)
[1]    16079 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

and the backtrace is listed as:

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007f90dd99a801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f90de57a52e in zmq::zmq_abort(char const*) () from /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
#3  0x00007f90de59ca67 in zmq::signaler_t::wait(int) () from /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
#4  0x00007f90de57ea5c in zmq::mailbox_t::recv(zmq::command_t*, int) () from /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
#5  0x00007f90de59e9c7 in zmq::socket_base_t::process_commands(int, bool) () from /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
#6  0x00007f90de59f726 in zmq::socket_base_t::recv(zmq::msg_t*, int) () from /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
#7  0x00007f90de5c4e8c in zmq_msg_recv () from /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5
#8  0x0000561da8eb18f3 in zmq::socket_t::recv(zmq::message_t*, int) ()
#9  0x0000561da8eb2b47 in Listener::start() ()
```

### Question

How to quit subscriber in a safe way according to a external signal? What's wrong with above code? Or is there a better structure and design to organize and handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Well written question! Does the problem still occur if you pass `std::launch::async` to `std::async`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It does occur for both `std::lanuch::async` and `std::lanuch::deferred` as parameter of `std::async`. And it occurs using `std::thread` and `join()` as well. @Filipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always keep the zmq context under the control of the main thread.  In this case I would do something like

pseudo code:

```
main()
{
context(1) // only one context
job1(context) // pass ref to the one context
job2(context) // pass ref to the one context
job1.join()
job2.join()
context.close()
}
```

If you structure means you can't do that then you need to think more about how you handle the shutdown.

Your code is calling control code (on the socket) in one thread

```
subscriber_.close();
controller_.close();
context_.close();
```

And the handling code (on the socket) in another

```
controller_.recv(&ctrl);
```

**Two reasons not to do this**

- zmq standard sockets are not thread safe
- you have a race condition where the socket and context may be destroyed while the recv thread is blocking. When it unblocks it's
  just going to fail in an undefined way as zmq is effectively dead (context closed) at
  this point.

You should open, use and close the socket in the same thread. In this case (subscriber_ object)  call `close()` on the socket in the `start()` thread when you get `ETERM` **or** `stop_` is true

Comment: Thank you, James. Yes, it is not safe to operate sockets in different threads. And your frame work that pass context under main is a good practice to follow. I solve this problem by use your suggestion and send a extra message after stop is called.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for @James' answer, I solved this problem myself and update code by following changes:

1. manage context in `main()` and pass it with `std::shared_ptr`;
2. close sockets in the thread creating it;
3. broadcast an extra message to flush zmq queue;
4. use `std::atomic<bool>` instead of `volatile` to type flag `stop_`.

As a result, we don't have to brutally destroy the `context` and catch `ETERM`, which is a unnatural way. And all sockets on all thread can quit safely.

In the end, I post the source code here. Hope it can help others encountered the same problem.

```cpp
class Broadcast {
public:
    Broadcast(std::shared_ptr<zmq::context_t> context):
        context_(context),
        publisher_(*context_, ZMQ_PUB),
        controller_(*context_, ZMQ_PUB)
    {
        publisher_.bind("tcp://*:5556");
        controller_.bind("tcp://*:5557");
    }

    ~Broadcast() {
        publisher_.close();
        controller_.close();
    }

    void start(){
        std::cout << "start Broadcast" << std::endl;
        // send data through publisher
        const int send_time = 5;
        const std::string foo_template("foo_");
        for(int i = 0; i < send_time; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            std::string foo = foo_template + std::to_string(i);
            zmq::message_t msg(foo.size());
            std::memcpy(msg.data(), foo.c_str(), foo.size());
            std::cout << "Broadcast: " << foo << std::endl;
            publisher_.send(msg);
        }
        // send stop control signal through controller
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        std::string stop("bar");
        zmq::message_t msg(stop.size());
        std::memcpy(msg.data(), stop.c_str(), stop.size());
        std::cout << "Broadcast Control Signal: " << stop << std::endl;
        controller_.send(msg);
        std::cout << "end Broadcast" << std::endl;

        // FIX: post extra message to flush zmq queue
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        std::string foo = foo_template + "end";
        zmq::message_t msg_end(foo.size());
        std::memcpy(msg_end.data(), foo.c_str(), foo.size());
        std::cout << "Broadcast: " << foo << std::endl;
        publisher_.send(msg_end);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<zmq::context_t> context_;
    zmq::socket_t  publisher_;
    zmq::socket_t  controller_;
}; // class Broadcast
```

```cpp
class Client {
public:
    Client(std::shared_ptr<zmq::context_t> context):
        stop_(false),
        context_(context),
        subscriber_(*context_, ZMQ_SUB),
        controller_(*context_, ZMQ_SUB)
    {
        int linger = 0;
        subscriber_.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
        controller_.connect("tcp://localhost:5557");
        subscriber_.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, nullptr, 0);
        controller_.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, nullptr, 0);
        subscriber_.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));
        controller_.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof(linger));
    }

    ~Client() {
        subscriber_.close();
        controller_.close();
    }

    void start() {
        stop_ = false;

        std::cout << "start Client" << std::endl;
        auto control_future = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]{ control(); });
        while(!stop_) {
            try {
                zmq::message_t msg;
                subscriber_.recv(&msg);
                std::string msg_str{static_cast<char*>(msg.data()), msg.size()};
                std::cout << "Received : " << msg_str << std::endl;
            } catch(const zmq::error_t& ex) {
                if(ex.num() != ETERM)
                    throw;
                break; // exit while loop
            }
        }
        std::cout << "wait control to join..." << std::endl;
        control_future.get();
        std::cout << "end Client" << std::endl;
    }

    void control() {
        while(!stop_) {
            zmq::message_t ctrl;
            controller_.recv(&ctrl);
            std::string ctrl_str{static_cast<char*>(ctrl.data()), ctrl.size()};
            std::cout << "Received  Control Signal: " << ctrl_str << std::endl;
            if(ctrl_str == "bar") {
                stop_ = true;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> stop_;
    std::shared_ptr<zmq::context_t> context_;
    zmq::socket_t  subscriber_;
    zmq::socket_t  controller_;
}; // class Client
```

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    auto gContext = std::make_shared<zmq::context_t>(1);

    Broadcast broadcast(gContext);
    Client    client(gContext);

    auto broadcast_future = std::async([&]{ broadcast.start(); });
    auto client_future    = std::async([&]{ client.start()   ; });

    broadcast_future.get();
    client_future.get();

    std::cout << "ALL COMPLETED" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it and run, one can obtain the correct result:

```sh
➜  zmq_safe_quit ./a.out
start Client
start Broadcast
Broadcast: foo_0
Received : foo_0
Broadcast: foo_1
Received : foo_1
Broadcast: foo_2
Received : foo_2
Broadcast: foo_3
Received : foo_3
Broadcast: foo_4
Received : foo_4
Broadcast Control Signal: bar
end Broadcast
Received  Control Signal: bar
Broadcast: foo_end
Received : foo_end
wait control to join...
end Client
ALL COMPLETED
```